# Errors within Main program using classes

Tags: c++, class, overloading

I just have a few errors of the same type in my main program. My college professor is not answering my emails so I have to resort to asking you guys. In my main program I have several errors somewhat similar to this: "request for member which is of non-class type." Program01 is basically testing every function in ListType.h, OListType.h, and UListType.h to make sure everything works correctly. Any help you can provide in a timely fashion will be appreciated.

Here is ListType.h:

```
#ifndef LISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define LISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

class ListType {
public:
 ListType(size_t=10);
 ListType(const ListType&);
 virtual ~ListType();
 virtual bool insert(int)=0;
 virtual bool eraseAll();
 virtual bool erase(int)=0;
 virtual bool find(int) const=0;
 size_t size() const;
 bool empty() const;
 bool full() const;
 friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const ListType&);
 const ListType& operator= (const ListType&);
protected:
 int *items;
 size_t capacity;
 size_t count;
};


#endif // LISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is ListType.cpp:

```
#include "ListType.h"

ListType::ListType (size_t a) {
 capacity = a;
 count = 0;
 items = new int [capacity];
}

ListType::ListType(const ListType& newlist) {
 capacity = newlist.capacity;
 count = newlist.count;
 items = new int [capacity];

 for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
     items[i] = newlist.items[i];
}

ListType::~ListType() {
 delete [] items;
}

bool ListType::eraseAll() {
 count = 0;
 return 0;
}

size_t ListType::size() const {
 return (count);
}

bool ListType::empty() const {
 return (count == 0);
}

bool ListType::full() const {
 return (count == capacity);
}


std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, const ListType& my_list) {
 if (!my_list.empty()) {

 for (size_t i = 0; i < my_list.count; ++i){
        out << my_list.items[i] << ',';
  }
 }
 return out;
}

const ListType& ListType::operator= (const ListType& rightObject) {
 if (this != & rightObject) {
     delete [] items;
     capacity = rightObject.capacity;
     count = rightObject.count;

     items = new int[capacity];

     for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
         items[i] = rightObject.items[i];
  }
 }
 return *this;
}
```

Here is UListType.h:

```
#ifndef ULISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define ULISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

class UListType: public ListType {
 public:
 UListType(size_t=10);
 bool insert(int);
 bool erase(int);
 bool find(int) const;
};


#endif // ULISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is UListType.cpp:

```
#include "ListType.h"
#include "UListType.h"


UListType::UListType (size_t c): ListType(c) {}


bool UListType::insert(int item) {
 if (full()) {
     int *newitems;
     capacity *=2;
     newitems = new int[capacity];
     for (size_t i =0; i < count; ++i){
         newitems[i] = items[i];
     }
     delete [] items;
     items = newitems;
 }
 items[count++] = item;
 return true;
}


bool UListType::erase(int item) {
 bool result = false;
 size_t i=0;
 while ( i < count && items [i] != item) {
     ++i;
 }
 if (i < count) {
     items[i] = items[-- count];
     result = true;
 }
 return result;
}


bool UListType::find(int item) const {
 size_t i = 0;
 while (i < count && items [i] != item) {
     ++i;
 }
 return i < count;
}
```

Here is OListType.h:

```
#ifndef OLISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#define OLISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
#include <iostream>

class OListType: public ListType {
public:
 OListType(size_t=10);
 bool insert(int);
 bool erase(int);
 bool find(int) const;
};


#endif // OLISTTYPE_H_INCLUDED
```

Here is OListType.cpp:

```
#include "ListType.h"
#include "OListType.h"

OListType::OListType(size_t c): ListType(c) {}


bool OListType::insert(int item) {
 size_t i = count;
 if (full()) {
     int *newitems;
     capacity *=2;
     newitems = new int[capacity];
     for(size_t j=0; j < count; ++j) {
         newitems[j] = items[i];
     }
     delete [] items;
     items = newitems;
 }

 while (i > 0 && items[i-1] > item){
       items[count++] = item;
     }
 return true;
}

bool OListType::erase(int item) {
 bool found=false;
 size_t i=0, j= count-1, mid;
 while (i <= j && !(found)){
     mid = (i + j)/2;
     if (item < items [mid])
         j = mid - 1;
     else if (item > items [mid])
         i = mid + 1;
     found = items [mid] == item;
 }
 if (found) {
     for (i = mid; i < count - 1; ++i) {
         items [i] = items [i +1];
     }
      --count;
 }
 return found;
}

bool OListType::find (int item) const {
bool found=false;
 size_t i=0, j= count-1, mid;
 while (i <= j && !(found)){
     mid = (i + j)/2;
     if (item < items [mid])
         j = mid - 1;
     else if (item > items [mid])
         i = mid + 1;
     found = items [mid] == item;
 }
 return found;
}
```

Here is Program01.cpp:

```
#include "ListType.h"
#include "UListType.h"
#include "OListType.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
 OListType list[5] = {165, 16, 118, 212, 104};
 UListType ranlist[10] = {243, 300, 154, 153, 592, 124, 195, 217, 289, 405};
 UListType UListAssignmentTest;
 OListType OListAssignmentTest;

 cout << "The Ordered List before operations:" << endl;
 cout << list << endl << endl;

 if(list.empty())                                     **<-- HERE BE THE ERROR**
     cout << "The list is empty, therefore it is true.";
 else
     cout << "The list is full or partially full, therefore it is false";
 cout << endl << endl;

 if(list.full())
     cout << "The list is full, therefore it is true.";
 else
     cout << "The list is partially full or empty, therefore it is false";
 cout << endl << endl;

 list.insert(25);
 cout << endl << endl;

 cout << "The Ordered list after Insert:" << endl;
 cout << list << endl << endl;

 list.find(25);
 cout << endl << endl;

 list.find(30);
 cout << endl << endl;

 list.erase(25);
 cout << endl << endl;

 cout << "The Ordered List after Erase:" << endl;
 cout << list << endl << endl;

 cout << "The Unordered List before operations:" << endl;
 cout << ranlist << endl << endl;

 if(ranlist.empty())
    cout << "The list is empty, therefore it is true.";
 else
     cout << "The list is full or partially full, therefore it is false";
 cout << endl << endl;

 if(ranlist.full())
     cout << "The list is full, therefore it is true.";
 else
     cout << "The list is partially full or empty, therefore it is false";
 cout << endl << endl;

 ranlist.insert(25);
 cout << endl << endl;

 cout << "The Unordered List after Insert:" << endl;
 cout << ranlist << endl << endl;

 ranlist.find(25);
 cout << endl << endl;

 ranlist.find(30);
 cout << endl << endl;

 ranlist.erase(25);
 cout << endl << endl;

 cout << "The Unordered List after Erase:" << endl;
 cout << ranlist << endl << endl;

 cout << "Testing Ordered List Assignment Operator" << endl;
 OListAssignmentTest = list;
 cout << OListAssignmentTest << endl << endl;

 cout << "Testing Unordered List Assignment Operator" << endl;
 UListAssignmentTest = ranlist;
 cout << UListAssignmentTest << endl << endl

 cout << "Testing Ordered List Copy Constructor" << endl;
 OListType OListVariable = list;
 cout << OListVariable << endl << endl;

 cout << "Testing Unordered List Copy Constructor" << endl;
 UListType UListVariable = ranlist;
 cout << UListVariable << endl << endl;

 cout << "Testing Erase All for OList" << endl;
 list.eraseAll();
 cout << "OList values now: " << list.empty() << endl << endl;

 cout << "Testing Erase All for UList" << endl;
 ranlist.eraseAll();
 cout << endl << "UList values now: " << ranlist.empty() << endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm sure your professor has better things to do than sift through tons of code looking for a vague description of an error. Surely that isn't the minimal program that demonstrates your error.

Comment: A couple of pointers when asking questions: 1) Post the entire error message, 2) Point out what line it is coming from (this is in the error message)

Comment: sorry guys I totally forgot about the error codes. Here:

error: request for member 'empty' in 'list', which is of non-class type 'OListType [5]'

If you can answer this one, I can basically knock off about 20 of the errors

Comment: @ldicus34: Okay found the line `list.empty()`, `list` is a plain old array, it doesn't have members like `empty`, etc. You need to access via subscript `list[0].empty();`, for each `OListType` in the array. Perhaps you are used to more dynamic languages.

Comment: nope first programming language. just don't have a clue what I'm doing.

Comment: I want to return a bool value for it in one go. I don't want to use a for loop so what would I change list into for that to work?

Comment: This is your first programming language and 1) You don't have a clue what you're doing (your words, not mine) and 2) You're coding a linked list class??!!

Comment: Actually, it looks like a dynamic array class -- but still...A beginner shouldn't be tackling something like this.

Comment: nope we're not at that subject yet. This is like a precursor to that subject. And I was being sarcastic about not knowing anything. Sarcastic comments don't help me any better than silence does.

Comment: it's a dynamic array class using pointers, if that makes it any clearer

Comment: I believe the general issue is that you're not understanding that the ListType is a single container that holds multiple values.  It isn't an array where you can just initialize it with 5 values (see your main() program and the error already pointed out by Jesse Good).  You're supposed to call member functions of the ListType class to insert each of those values.

Comment: okay the last comment is what helped on this. I have no errors but now the program crashes. Apparently my overloading of the << operator is not working as list still has nothing in it. any ideas?

Comment: Work on the insert and erase functions and make sure they are bulletproof or close to it (and use the debugger).  Streaming operators at this stage is secondary (in my opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
OListType list[5] = {165, 16, 118, 212, 104};
```

This line declares an array of 5 OListType types.  This doesn't seem correct.

You want to declare one OLIstType and insert 5 values into it.  If not, please clarify what that line is supposed to denote.

Here is probably what you are supposed to do:

```
OListType list;
list.insert(165);
list.insert(16); // etc...
```